# Weighted Centroid of an Array

Tags: math, image-processing, centroid

So I have a 2-dimensional array representing a coordinate plane, an image. On that image, I am looking for "red" pixels and finding (hopefully) the location of a red LED target based on all of the red pixels found by my camera. Currently, I'm simply slapping my crosshairs onto the centroid of all of the red pixels:

```
// pseudo-code

for(cycle_through_pixels)
{
   if( is_red(pixel[x][y]) )
   {
      vals++; // total number of red pixels
      cx+=x;  // sum the x's
      cy+=y;  // sum the y's
   }
}
cx/=vals; // divide by total to get average x
cy/=vals; // divide by total to get average y

draw_crosshairs_at(pixel[cx][cy]); // found the centroid
```

The problem with this method is that while this algorithm naturally places the centroid closer to the largest blob (the area with the most red pixels), I am still seeing my crosshairs jump off the target when a bit of red flickers off to the side due to glare or other minor interferences.

My question is this:

How do I change this pattern to look for a more *weighted* centroid? Put simply, I want to make the larger blobs of red much more important than the smaller ones, possibly even ignoring far-out small blobs altogether.

Comment: If you had to "identical" red dots on the left and on the right of your plane. Would the centroid algorithm not draw your cross-hair in the center of the image where there is no red? The problem would still persist if you added weight to the equation even though it would be less likely.

Comment: Yes, that is a case in which the algorithm performs quite horribly. However, this all pertains to an actual demonstration I plan to give involving the tracking of a specific target, and the idea is that while there will be some interference, there should never be anything even close to identical to the target on the field (it's a very distinguishable target). The idea here is to make the algorithm pay more attention to my larger source of red while maintaining some ability to keep it "locked on" if it gets farther away or slightly hindered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find the [connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling) in the image and only include those components that have a total size above a certain threshold in your centroid calcuation.

Comment: I came up with the basic idea of this concept on my own and threw it away thinking it was too outlandish, and I never would have known what to call it in a Google search. Thank you so much for showing this to me, I'll try it when I get the chance.

Comment: It is a very common image processing operation.  If you are using a image processing toolkit, it may have a function that does this already.

Comment: This worked spectacularly! First off, implementing this concept did exactly what I wanted: my little floating crosshairs stays towards the center of the largest blob on the screen, almost ignoring small interference and only giving slight tugs at larger errant splotches. In addition to this, my crosshairs has become incredibly more stable; whereas before it would jump around in a glitchy manner whenever the drone moved slightly or the lighting changed, now it flows smoothly around the screen.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest (and maybe naïve) answer would be: instead of counting just the pixel value, count also the surrounding 8 pixels (in a total of 9). Now, each value took can be from 0 to 9, and includes greater values for blobs with the same color. Now, instead of `vals++` you'll be incrementing the value by the number of pixels in the surrounding area too.

Comment: It's interesting that you suggest this, and even more interesting that you call it naïve, because I actually considered something much like this briefly before dismissing it as a silly and hack-ish notion. I told myself I should stick to more conventional paths. However, as you and tkerwin have showed me today, I'm not the only one to have come up with this concept, and it is apparently widely-used and quite effective. I'll try implementing it tomorrow. Thanks!